# How to set contentbounds when scaling a control inside a TScrollBox

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, firemonkey, scaling

I have a TScrollBox in which I put a TRectangle with Align = Center and sized such that it clearly fits the content area. Next I have a trackbar controlling the TRectangle.scale (both X and Y). When the scale is < 1 (reducing the layout) then the vertical scrollbar appears and when the scale is > 1 the scrollbar disappears.

What is the best approach to ensure that the scrollbar properly shows the scrollbars, taking into account the rectangle scale?

I did try scaling the scrollbar.content but that does not support centering the rectangle itself.

Comment: Admittedly, quite an unexpected behaviour. If you leave the `scale` of the rectangle alone and instead adjust `width` and `height`, the size of the rectangle behaves and also the scrollbars. I believe you adjusted the scale in order that other controls on the rectangle would scale. They do if you set their align property to `scale` even though the rectangles scale is not changed. Just a note about scaled controls: don't let them resize down to 0 on any dimension, they stay locked at 0 thenafter.

Comment: Thanx @TomBrunberg. THe align=scale alternative does not provide the user experience I am after. I guess this one will go to quality central.